# How to Override BibliographyAddNewSource of Word in VSTO Add-in

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop, office-addins, word-addins

In my VSTO Word Add-in, I have added the built-in BibliographyAddNewSource button to my custom Ribbon. I want to be able to add new source to the Current List of sources without citing the added source in the document. Is there a way I can override the OK button of the Create Source form so that the new source can simply be added to the Sources List without citing it in the document body automatically?

If their is an alternative way to achieve this please I will want to know too.

Comment: Do you have any codes or pictures that you can show us? I'm not sure what you mean by "current list of sources". It would be helpful if you can share more details.

Comment: @UfguFugullu, when you click the *Insert Citation* dropdown menu in the *Citations & Bibliography* group of the *Reference* tab in Microsoft Word ribbon, there is a button to *Add New Source* if the document does not contain the source you want to insert as citation in the document. When you add the new source to the document, the document will update its list of sources and include the new you've just added and then go on to automatically Insert the source as a citation in the current cursor position. I don't want it to insert the citation when I add. I want to insert later.

Comment: You should take these information to your question and add screenshots and your current codes.